# Update the Select Dropdown state only after clicking submit in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on country selector component I want to update the state value only when user click on submit button.

1. I tried to store selected drop down value in temp variable But the select drop down value will not reflect in UI again get the old value in UI

HeaderLeftComponent (Here i am using drop down state)

```
const HeaderLeftSection = ( props ) => {

const [showCountry, setShowCountry] = useState(false);
const [ShowAccount, setShowAccount] = useState(false);
const [ShowWishlist, setShowWishlist] = useState(false);

const [countrySelector, setCountrySelector] = useState({
    country: "IN",
    currency: "INR"
});

const handleShowCountry = () => {
    setShowCountry(true);
}

const handleHideCountry = () => {
    setShowCountry(false);
}

const handleShowAccount = () => {
    setShowAccount(true);
}

const handleHideAccount = () => {
    setShowAccount(false);
}

const handleShowWishlist = () => {
    setShowWishlist(true);
}

const handleHideWishlist = () => {
    setShowWishlist(false);
}

const handleCountryAndCurrencyChange = (item) => {
    const Country = item;
}

const handleSaveCountry = (item) => {
    alert();
    setShowCountry(false);
}

return (
    <>
        <Model 
            show={showCountry} 
            hide={ handleHideCountry } 
            classModal="Country__selector--modal" 
            handleButtonClicked={handleSaveCountry}
            ModelHeader="true"
            ModelFooter="true"
            ButtonOneText="Save & Continue"
            ButtonSecondText="Cancel"
            block="true">
                <CountrySelector 
                    countrySelector={countrySelector} 
                    handleCountryAndCurrencyChange={handleCountryAndCurrencyChange} 
                />
        </Model>

        <Model 
            show={ShowAccount} 
            hide={handleHideAccount}  
            classModal="Account__form--modal"
            ModelHeader="true"
            ModelHeaderText="SIGN IN">
                <Login />
        </Model>

        <Model show={ShowWishlist} hide={handleHideWishlist} ModelHeader="true" ModelHeaderText="WISHLIST" classModal="Wishlist__form--modal">
            <p>WishList Test</p>
        </Model>

        <div className="Header__left-section">
            <div className="Header__left--countrySelector mr-5 icon" onClick={handleShowCountry}>
                <span>{countrySelector.country}</span>
                <span>{countrySelector.currency}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="Header__left--account mr-5">
                <Icon.Person className="icon" onClick={handleShowAccount}/>
            </div>
            <div className="Header__left--wishlist">
                <Icon.Heart className="icon" onClick={handleShowWishlist}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
)
}

  export default HeaderLeftSection;
```

Country Selector Component

```
   const CountrySelector = ( props ) => {

return (
    <>
        <p>Shipping somewhere else?</p>
        <p>Simply select the destination you would like to deliver to and the currency you would like to shop in.</p>
        <Select List={countryList} label="Delivery To" size="sm" value={props.countrySelector.country} handleCountryAndCurrencyChange={props.handleCountryAndCurrencyChange}/>
        <Select List={currencyList} label="Shop in" size="sm" value={props.countrySelector.currency} handleCountryAndCurrencyChange={props.handleCountryAndCurrencyChange}/>
    </>
  )
}
```

Below is the select drop down component

```
const Select = ( props ) => {
return (
    <>
        <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>{props.label}</Form.Label>
            <Form.Control as="select" size={props.size} value={props.value} custom onChange={(event) => props.handleCountryAndCurrencyChange(event.target.value)}>
                {
                    props.List.map((item, index) => {
                        return <option key={item.code} value={item.code}>{item.name}</option>
                    })
                }
            </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
    </>
)
}
```

Expected :

When user selects on country selector drop down It should reflect on UI (User can see) but its state should not update. State only update only when user click on submit button

Thanks in advance

Comment: State - is what on UI by definition

Comment: Sate is nothing but value (Selected Drop down value should show in UI but it should not update value (state) in other component) It should update only when user click on submit

Comment: Looks like you have controlled inputs, so they are driven by state updates. It's just how they work. Neither of the code snippets you've included have any state so I assume there is more to the story. Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example so we've more context around this "state" and form submission you reference.

Comment: Your component doesn't have its own state and uses parent's state. Controlled Components have separate state - https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why wait until form is being submitted to update the state? What's the point then? You could convert over to uncontrolled inputs (i.e. no state controlling value) and use the form's `onSubmit` event object to get all the field values.